# Am I correctly computing $\Delta(x^\overline m)$?

Tags: discrete-calculus

Notation definitions according to [Concrete Mathematics](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/concrete-mathematics-a/9780134389974/):

$\Delta f(x) = f(x+1) - f(x)$

$x^\underline m = x(x-1)...(x-m+1)$, integer $m \ge 0$  (Read aloud as "x to the m falling.")

$x^\overline m = x(x+1)...(x+m-1)$, integer $m \ge 0$  (Read aloud as "x to the m rising.")

---

I derived $\Delta f(x^\underline m)$ for myself, and it is also given in the book, as: $mx^\underline{m-1}$ (A fun result to calculate!)

I then tried to compute $\Delta(x^\overline m)$, which is not shown in the book, and got the slightly more unwieldy result:

$m(x+1)^\overline{m-1}$

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials#Relation_to_umbral_calculus) (which uses different notation), shows the result for the falling factorial, but then only says, "A similar result holds for the rising factorial," without specifying what that result is.

Am I correctly computing $\Delta(x^\overline m)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s the correct result, so you probably are; the computation is

$$\begin{align*}
\Delta(x^{\overline m})&=(x+1)^{\overline m}-x^{\overline m}\\
&=(x+1)^{\overline{m-1}}(x+m)-x(x+1)^{\overline{m-1}}\\
&=m(x+1)^{\overline{m-1}}\;.
\end{align*}$$